# OpenCV Dynamic segmentation method for blurred or degraded image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have implemented segmentation for given images, but images may vary based on different color. How can I separate background from the foreground where foreground contains hollow circle/filled circle only. My goal is to find threshold value automatically based on color of image.
[Sample images][1]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

image =cv2.imread("cropped2/pnr6.jpg")
img = image.copy()
MARKER_LOWER_BOUND = ( 0,  0,  0)
MARKER_UPPER_BOUND = (255, 255, 25)
marker_seg_mask = cv2.inRange(img, MARKER_LOWER_BOUND, MARKER_UPPER_BOUND)
cv2.imshow("thresold.jpg",marker_seg_mask)
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit better what you are trying to do please? What result do you expect?

Comment: @MarkSetchell For OMR based application, i am trying to evaluate roll number from filled circle. But segmentation is not working properly for different quality and color images. So i need bit information that which technique can better separate hollow circle and filled circle. How can i get to know circle is filled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` function, which should do what you need.
From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

> Adaptive Thresholding
>
> In the previous section, we used a global value as threshold value.
>   But it may not be good in all the conditions where image has different
>   lighting conditions in different areas. In that case, we go for
>   adaptive thresholding. In this, the algorithm calculate the threshold
>   for a small regions of the image. So we get different thresholds for
>   different regions of the same image and it gives us better results for
>   images with varying illumination.